# Harry Potter fanfic: Snape is ordered to raise Harry

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Definitely read it on FFN. I last read it about 10 years ago; it was definitely unfinished at the time. The profile pic had a fox in it.

Key details:

- Harry is either a baby or possibly a toddler.
- Dumbledore essentially either makes Snape take Harry in or guilts him into doing it.
- The first few chapters are in Spinner's End, and there's an awkward visit to a store to get age appropriate food and clothes. I remember him being very annoyed about how cutesy the clothes are. He accidentally makes Harry cry because he doesn't want to buy Harry a panda shirt. (Because of Harry's past abuse, he cries silently.)
- Dumbledore tries to get baby Harry to call Snape either Dada or papa.
- Snape tries to do the self-soothing thing so Harry can sleep by himself, but all that leads to is a night full of Harry calling out for "'Nape" and Snape eventually losing the battle.
- Harry calls Snape "'Nape" and himself "Pot" or "Pot-pot".
- Snape has a difficult time playing with Harry so he disguises it as "teaching" because he feels ridiculous saying things like "vroom" or making animal noises.
- Because he's so formal he only calls Harry "Potter". Which results in Harry calling himself "Pot".
- Snape eventually has to go back to teaching with Harry in tow and proves that yes, he is still a scary teacher even with a cute little baby hanging around (this happens after Harry embarrasses him). All his students think Harry is actually his son.
- Draco and Harry playdates occur.
- Lucius Malfoy low-key doesn't want Voldemort to return.
- Snape is Draco's godfather.
- Tom Riddle's diary becomes a plot point, as in they want to uncover the secrets of the diary.
- Professor Trelawney keeps trying to flirt with Snape (there's a particular scene during a Halloween party where Snape uses Harry as a shield).

Answer (score 7):

[*Protector*](https://m.fanfiction.net/s/6763798/1/Protector), by Foxwithgrayeyes.

The brief description give is:

> Dumbledore urges Snape to look after Harry after witnessing the
> Dursley's abuse and Snape reluctantly becomes parent figure to a very
> small Harry Potter.

There is mention of clothing with a Panda on:

> Suddenly Harry made an impatient mmm-ing sound. He pointed his finger
> at a white shirt with black sleeves and a big smiling panda on the
> front, eating a stick of bamboo.

The first mention of Snape as 'Nape' is in chapter 9.

Comment: Is the story finished now by any chance?

Comment: Last updated in 2015, and appears to reach some sort of conclusion. Based purely on reading the last couple of paragraphs, so no idea if other plotlines are resolved or left open.